# Derivative of a matrix with respect to a matrix

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

If $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ are matrices such that the function $\mathbf z=\mathbf x^n \mathbf y^m $ is well defined, how can I find the derivatives
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf z}{\partial \mathbf x} \qquad \frac{\partial \mathbf z}{\partial \mathbf y}
$$

From some example in Quantum Mechanics I know that, as an example, if $\mathbf z =\mathbf x^2 \mathbf y$ than
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf z}{\partial \mathbf x} =\mathbf{xy+ yx}
$$

But where can I find the proof for this result?
More general: where can I find some references about this kind of calculus with matrices?

---

Added after the answers.

My reference is the historical paper of Born and Jordan on foundation of matrix mechanic (it can be found in https://archive.org/details/SourcesOfQuantumMechanics).
Here, in the paragraph 2 ( pag.282 of ref.), is defined the ''Symbolic differentiation'' of a matrix function and, as an example, is given:
$$
\mathbf{
y=x_1^n x_2^m \qquad \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_1}=x_1^{n-1}x_2^m+x_1^{n-2}x_2^mx_1+\cdots +x_2^mx_1^{n-1}
}
$$

so it seems totally different from the answers. Is it wrong or it depends only on a different definition of the derivative?

My problem is to justify the result of Born and Jordan that is essential to prove the  classical commutation relation of Quantum Mechanic.

If the definition of Born is so different from the ''standard'' mathematical definition, how we can motivate such difference?

Comment: The derivative should be a $4$-dimensional matrix. Or, more precisely, matrix-valued function.

Comment: I had a quick glance at the book and left more confused. I can only presume there is some implied convention that I am missing, for example, on p.284 they have $(ab)' = a'b'$ where the $'$ seems to be transpose.This differs with the usual $(ab)'=b'a'$. On p.282, Equation (14), I have no idea what the $l$ in $\delta_{l,k}$ means.

Comment: Contrary to their statement at the start of the Symbolic Differentiation section, the rules of differentiation are exactly the same as usual except that we do not in general have commutativity as with scalars. And as Ted mentioned below, linear operators on matrices cannot always be represented as premultiplication be a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to guess & verify symbolically:

In the following, $x=(x_1,x_2)$, where $x_1,x_2$ are matrices, and similarly, $h=(h_1,h_2)$.

Using the example in the question, $f(x)=x_1^nx_2^m$, then
$f(x+h) -f(x)= (x_1+h_1)^n (x_2+h_2)^m- x_1^nx_2^m$, and a little work shows that
$f(x+h) -f(x)= (\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x_1^k h_1 x_1^{n-k-1} ) x_2^m +x_1^n (\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} x_2^k h_2 x_2^{m-k-1} )+ O( \|h\|^2)$ from which we see that
$Df(x)h = (\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x_1^k h_1 x_1^{n-k-1} ) x_2^m +x_1^n (\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} x_2^k h_2 x_2^{m-k-1} )$.

So, with $f(x)=x_1^2x_2$, we have
$Df(x)h = (h_1x_1+x_1h_1)x_2+x_1^2 h_2$.

Comment: thank you. I added something to my question to better clarify my problem.

Comment: I don't understand the starting point:  I suppose that $h$ is a matrix, but what is the relation of $h$ with $h_1$ and $h_2$?

Comment: $x=(x_1,x_2)$, where $x_1,x_2$ are matrices. Same for $h=(h_1,h_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

The best suggestion is to work with the definition of the directional derivative. If $f(\mathbf x,\mathbf y) = \mathbf x^2\mathbf y$, then if we change $\mathbf x$ in direction $\mathbf v$, we have
\begin{align*}
D_{(\mathbf v,\mathbf 0)}f(\mathbf x,\mathbf y) &= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf v,\mathbf y) - f(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)}t = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(\mathbf x+t\mathbf v)^2\mathbf y - \mathbf x^2\mathbf y}t \\ &= \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(\mathbf x^2 + t\mathbf x\mathbf v + t\mathbf v\mathbf x+ \mathbf v^2)\mathbf y - \mathbf x^2\mathbf y}t = (\mathbf x\mathbf v + \mathbf v\mathbf x)\mathbf y,
\end{align*}
so your formula is totally incorrect (for starters, there's no way $\mathbf y$ can end up on the other side of $\mathbf x$). More importantly, there's no way to write the correct formula as a simple matrix multiplied by the vector $\mathbf v$ because the vector $\mathbf v$ gets intertwined.

Now if you think of $\mathbf x = [x_{ij}]$ and you want to compute $\partial f/\partial x_{ij}$, then you apply what I wrote with $\mathbf v = E_{ij}$, the matrix with a $1$ in the $ij$-position and $0$'s elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you @Ted. I added something to my question to better clarify my problem.

Comment: Anyway, Using your definition, what is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}}$?

Comment: Their formula seems to be nonsense to me. The fact that they're commuting the two matrices suggests it's just wrong. Please give me a definition of $\partial f/\partial\mathbf x$. As I said, the linear map $T(\mathbf v) = (\mathbf x\mathbf v+\mathbf v\mathbf x)\mathbf y$ is not represented by $A_{\mathbf x,\mathbf y}\mathbf v$ for any matrix $A$.

Comment: The definition is given in the referred page. My doubt is if that  Born-Jordan definition of the partial derivative  is compatible with a standard  mathematical definition of the derivative of a function of more matrices variables with respect to  one of such variables.

Comment: Yeah, this is some formal procedure that has (in general) nothing whatsoever to do with differentiation of functions.

Comment: They seem to imply that $(ab)'=a'b'$ where $'$ seems to be transposition, so there is definitely something odd going on.

Comment: @copper.hat, or any process of row and column swaps ... which also do not obey that rule. I have not expended any energy on it, and I don't intend to. The privilege of being retired :P

Comment: @TedShifrin: thank you. I'm reading the book *The Historical Development of Quantum Theory* and it seems that this strange definition of derivative was introduced by Pascual Jordan with physical motivations.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\d{\delta}\def\p{\partial}
\def\G{{\cal E}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}\def\BR#1{\L\{#1\R\}}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\E{\color{blue}{\G}}
$Since $\BR{x,y,z}$ are $2^{nd}$order tensors (i.e. matrices), the gradients $\BR{\grad{z}{x},\grad{z}{y}}$ are $4^{th}$order tensors.

The best way to handle this is to use index notation.

Another approach is to introduce a special isotropic $4^{th}$order tensor $\E$, whose components can be written using Kronecker deltas as
$$\E_{ijk\ell} = \d_{ik}\d_{j\ell} = \begin{cases}
\o\quad{\rm if}\;\;i=k{\;\;\rm and\;\;}j=\ell \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$
This tensor can also be defined as the gradient of a matrix with respect to itself, i.e.
$$\E = \grad{X}{X}$$
The tensor has some interesting algebraic properties
$$\eqalign{
&A\cdot B\cdot C^T = \LR{A\cdot\E\cdot C}:B \\
&A = \E:A = A:\E \\
}$$
where the single and double contraction products are defined as
$$\eqalign{
\LR{A\cdot\E\cdot C}_{ijk\ell}
 &= \sum_{p=1}^P\sum_{q=1}^Q A_{i\c{p}}\,\E_{\c{p}jk\c{q}}\,C_{\c{q}\ell} \\
\LR{\E:A}_{ij}
 &= \sum_{p=1}^P\sum_{q=1}^Q \E_{ij\c{pq}}\,A_{\c{pq}} \\
}$$
Now calculate the differential and gradient of $z$ with respect to $x$.
$$\eqalign{
 z &= x^n\cdot y^m \\
dz &= \c{dx^n}\cdot y^m \\
 &= \c{\sum_{j=1}^n x^{n-j}\cdot dx\cdot x^{j-1}}\cdot y^m \\
 &= {\sum_{j=1}^n x^{n-j}\cdot\E\cdot\LR{x^{j-1}y^m}^T}:dx \\
\grad{z}{x}
 &= {\sum_{j=1}^n x^{n-j}\cdot\E\cdot\LR{x^{j-1}y^m}^T} \\
}$$
A similar calculation yields the gradient with respect to $y$.
$$\eqalign{
\grad{z}{y}
 &= {\sum_{k=1}^m x^n\cdot y^{m-k}\cdot\E\cdot\LR{y^{k-1}}^T} \\
}$$
Using the standard basis matrices $E_{ij}$ (mentioned in Ted Shifrin's answer), you can extract an expression for the component-wise matrix-valued gradients
$$\eqalign{
\grad{z}{y_{ij}}
 &= \LR{\grad{z}{y}}:E_{ij} \\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^m x^n\cdot y^{m-k}\cdot E_{ij}\cdot {y^{k-1}} \\
}$$